# Handle environment variables for multiple Cloud Run (GCP) services on Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I have multiple Google Cloud Run (GCP)services that I am deploying through Terraform. Each of these services need different environment variables like some services need Google Cloud Storage bucket name, another service need the db connection string etc.

What is the best way to handle these environment variables via terraform so I don't have to write one google_cloud_run_service resource blocks for each service.

Here is my sample code. The way I have set up currently, all the env variables are getting passed to every cloud run service that I deploy. What is the best way to pass specific env variables to specific services?

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "run_service" {
  project  = var.gcp_project_id
  provider = google-beta
  location = var.region

  # Iterate through key-value maps of [service_name:{image:image_name,email:email}]
  for_each = var.cloudrun_services
  name     = each.key

  template {
    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/cloudsql-instances"   = var.postgres-conn-str
        "run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-connector" = "projects/${var.gcp_project_id}/locations/${var.region}/connectors/${var.vpc_connector_name}"
        "run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-egress"    = "private-ranges-only"
        "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale"        = 100
        
      }
    }
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.gcp_project_id}/${each.value.image}" # TODO change name, Grab latest TAG
        
        env {
          name  = "CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"
          value = var.postgres-conn-str
        }
        env {
          name  = "QUARANTINE_BUCKET"
          value = var.quarantine_bucket_name
        }

        env {
          name = "DB_NAME"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = var.postgres-dbname
              key  = "latest"
            }
          }
        }
        env {
          name = "DB_USER"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = var.postgres-username
              key  = "latest"
            }
          }
        }
        env {
          name = "DB_PASS"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = var.postgres-username-pwd
              key  = "latest"
            }
          }
        }
        env {
          name = "REDIS_HOST"
          value = var.memorystore-host
        }
        env {
          name = "APP_URL"
          value = var.app_url
        }
      }
    }
  }
  # Removing the below metadata block breaks Cloud Run. Official docs shows included.
  #https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-secret-environment-variables
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      generated-by                      = "magic-modules"
      "run.googleapis.com/launch-stage" = "ALPHA"
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
  autogenerate_revision_name = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      metadata.0.annotations,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a terraform question. AFAIK, the best way is to create a `local` variable. In it, create an array of object. Each object equals a Cloud Run deployment (image, env vars, secret (don't forget to put sensitive data in secret manager instead of Env Var in plain text),...). Iterate over this array and call your cloud run deployment module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, this is TF question. Could you elaborate more on how would I set it(local variable) up and iterate and still retain the ability to set specific variables for the specific cloud run service

Comment: Hashicorp has tutorials to teach you HCL: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/count?in=terraform/configuration-language

Comment: Option1: Recently I found `https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform` which can read a terraform files and create resource. I believe you create a samples template and using python to fill up the details and run them ? Option2: how about creating your own terraform module?